# Bison reduce conflict with look ahead token set

Tags: bison

How would I fix this `LR(2)` (I think) grammar section? I want to parse both `type[]` and `type` in this rule but I get a reduce conflict:

```
expression:
   ... other expressions
    | expression LSQUARE expression RSQUARE
    | expression KW_IS type
    | expression KW_AS type
   ... other expressions
    ;


type
    : fqtypename LSQUARE RSQUARE
    | live_types LSQUARE RSQUARE
    | fqtypename
    | live_types
    ;

fqtypename
    : identifier
    | fqtypename DOT identifier
    ;

live_types
    : KW_INT | KW_DOUBLE | KW_BOOL | KW_STRING
    ;
```

The error I get is:

```
State 113

   56 type: fqtypename • LSQUARE RSQUARE
   58     | fqtypename •
   63 fqtypename: fqtypename • DOT identifier

    LSQUARE  shift, and go to state 123
    DOT      shift, and go to state 21

    LSQUARE   [reduce using rule 58 (type)]
    DOT       [reduce using rule 58 (type)]
    $default  reduce using rule 58 (type)


State 114

   57 type: live_types • LSQUARE RSQUARE
   59     | live_types •

    LSQUARE  shift, and go to state 124

    LSQUARE   [reduce using rule 59 (type)]
    $default  reduce using rule 59 (type)
```

I tried to recreate it as minimal reproducible example:

```
%require "3.0"
%defines

%define api.pure full
%define parse.trace

%token LSQUARE '['
%token RSQUARE ']'
%token DOT '.'
%token IS "is"

%%

example
    :expression
    ;
    
expression
    : expression LSQUARE expression RSQUARE
    | expression IS type
    | identifier
    ;
    
type
    : fqtypename LSQUARE RSQUARE
    | fqtypename
    ;

fqtypename
    : identifier
    | fqtypename DOT identifier
    ;

identifier: 
    "blah"
    ;

%%
```

With error:

```
State 10

5 type: fqtypename • LSQUARE RSQUARE
6     | fqtypename •
8 fqtypename: fqtypename • DOT identifier

LSQUARE  shift, and go to state 13
DOT      shift, and go to state 14

LSQUARE   [reduce using rule 6 (type)]
$default  reduce using rule 6 (type)
```

Comment: That's not enough of the grammar to diagnose the problem. It's like just showing the line `x = y / z;` and asking why you get a divide-by-zero exception. Obviously, the divide-by-zero is the result of `z` being 0, but the question is "How did `z` acquire the value 0?` and the line where `z` is proven to be 0 doesn't tell you that. Similarly, I can look at your question and tell you that `type` is used somewhere in a context where it could be followed by a `[`. Maybe that's enough of a clue for you. I hope so, because it's all I've got. If you need more, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @rici making minimal reproducible example would be rather hard considered custom lexer (I would have to make yacc instead that I would have to read upon). But I added the only rule where `type` appears. What I find weird is that this conflict appears in those rules not the expression rule.

Comment: The [mre] doesn't have to be the same language as you are parsing. It just has to exhibit the same conflict. You could make all the tokens simple keywords, and it doesn't change the essence of the syntax.

Comment: @rici Added something that produces same error (?). No idea it will help in my concrete case later but better than nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that's an LR(2) grammar. After the parser reads `expression IS identifier`, with `[` as the lookahead token, it needs to see what comes after the `[` to know whether to immediately reduce `identifier` to a `type`, or to include `[]` in the `type`.

Although it's always possible to transform an LALR(2) grammar into an equivalent LALR(1) grammar, the algorithm produces enormous grammars. (It can recreate the original parse tree, though.) Sometimes it's possible to come up with a more streamlined solution for specific grammars, but I don't see an obvious one in this case.

A common solution is to put the deferral logic into the lexical analyser. For example, on finding a `[`, the lexical analyser could read the next (non-whitespace token); if that token is a `]`, then it can return a fabricated `LRSQUARE` (`"[]"`) token; otherwise, it holds onto the new lookahead token for the next call and immediately returns `LSQUARE`. That's basically the way Bison itself handles the LR(2) aspect of optional semicolons. (If you use a push parser, this is slightly easier to implement since a single lexical analyser action can send two tokens, one at a time.)

Another solution is to use a GLR parser, which allows arbitrary lookahead by exploring multiple possibilities in parallel, when necessary. In the LR(2) case, the additional overhead is minimal, but it still exists.

Comment: I did not think about the [] single token as possibility, I will test it out!